# Do I capitalize "gulf" when referring to the Gulf of Mexico?

Tags: capitalization

In referring to the Gulf of Mexico as "the gulf," do I capitalize "gulf?"
Example: "We're going to the gulf (or Gulf) in August." I'm using the Chicago Manual of Style, 15th ed., but can't find a clear answer.

Answer (score 2):

"The Gulf" is usually capitalized, because it's functioning as a short form of the name "the Gulf of Mexico" rather than as an ordinary use of the common noun *gulf*. (Of course, the Gulf of Mexico *is* a gulf, so it's not wrong to write "the gulf" in a context where you've just referred to it. But it's also an "ocean basin", so an easy test is: in any given occurrence of "the gulf", could you happily write "the ocean basin" instead? If not, then it's because you're using "the Gulf" as a short name, and should capitalize it.)